# Common way to stop repetitive requests in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, submit

As it is known AngularJS doesn't support synchronous requests. Most of what it allows for that are promises, but the question is not about that. I came across a problem, that getting response might take longer than person expects and the person might resubmit data. I would like to prevent it.

Are there any common built-in ways to do that?

Comment: yes - disable the button that triggers the request - make sure you show a 'working' icon / gif so the user knows the computer is thinking AND make sure nothing takes long enough that the user would want to re-submit in the first place!

Comment: You just named common steps for that. What I'm asking is wether AngularJS have something buil-in for that scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-disabled` bound to a property on the controller that you set to `true` before the xhr and `false` after the xhr completes. Click event and therefore `ng-click` will not file while a button is disabled.

Documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

**Update**
If you want to use `ng-disabled` with *any* element (e.g. `a`) you can use a custom click handler e.g.:

```
yourApp.directives.directive('myClick', ['$parse',function ($parse): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',        
        link: (scope, element:JQuery, attrs) => {
            var fn = $parse(attrs.picClick);
            element.on('click', function (event) {

                // The core disabled logic detection
                if (attrs.disabled) return;

                scope.$apply(function () {
                    fn(scope, { $event: event });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Of course, you should style your element differently for when it has the attribute `disabled` set to true.

**Another way**
Alternatively you can use a pair multually exclusive elements, only one shown at a time using something as simple as an (`ng-show`)

Comment: Would it work on a `<a href="#" ng-click="doSomething()">...</a>` as well? Since I'm seeing, that the allowed element for that is `INPUT` element.

Comment: I assume, that under "Another way" you mean two either buttons or anchors, that are show under diff. circumstances.

Comment: @Eugene yes. that is what i meant